# Rationalizing the denominator of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify 
>   $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$$

I think this should be expressed without square roots at the denominator. I tried to multiply by conjugate.

Comment: What did you get when you multiplied through by the conjugate?

Comment: let $x = 2+\sqrt{2}$. that might help

Comment: @user29418  Why would that substitution help?

Answer (score 3):

I used conjugates twice, got
$$ \sqrt 2 \cdot  \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2} \cdot \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2}} $$
Perhaps these can be multiplied together to make something nice. I don't know. Note that no information about the source of the question is given.

Comment: @user0410 yes, I see where I was careless. Edited in

Comment: You know Professor Jagy. I had this phrase before you post it. In fact, I thought the answer was pretty straightforward and probably OP could calculate that phrase, so I didn't post it. Anyway thank you for editing.

Comment: @user0410 I encourage you to post answers, at least sometimes; it is worthwhile to practice presenting ideas in a readable form.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your notification.

Answer (score 2):

So, you multiply by the denominator over the denominator to get rid of the first square root (while still just technically multiplying only by 1):
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}   \times \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} =
\frac{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}
$$
Now you have an expression that can be multiplied by a conjugate, so that’s what we do:
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\times\frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\right)\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}{(2-\sqrt{2})}
$$
This can also be multiplied by its conjugate:
$$
\frac{\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\right)\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}{(2-\sqrt{2})}=\frac{\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\right)\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(2+\sqrt2\right)}{2}
$$
So, we’ve finally got an expression with a rationalized denominator.
I'd just leave the numerator unsimplified, as it's kind of hard to do and I know I'd definitely make a mistake (If your teacher/professor wants you to multiply out the numerator they're crazy;)).

Comment: there is not usually a teacher or professor involved with this sort of question. All over the world, there are contests and lists of contest preparation questions, available online. Where was I: sometimes that is a real difficulty, when a problem is distorted, people waste their time on something impossible or very difficult.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you Brian. I'm sure that will help a lot in the future!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}=\\\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}=\\\frac{2 \cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\\
\frac{2\cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} \cdot \frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\\\frac{2\cdot(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})\cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2-\sqrt{2}}=\\
\frac{2\cdot(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})\cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2-\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}=\\\frac{2\cdot(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})\cdot (2+\sqrt{2})\cdot \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}=\\
(2+\sqrt{2}) \cdot (2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}) \cdot\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}
$$

Comment: I suggest you, please let $x^2=\frac{4}{{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$ and then obtain $ x^2=2 \cdot  (2 + \sqrt 2) \cdot (2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2})$ and finally get the desired result. I hope you find this note  useful.

Comment: @user0410 I wonder how you get $x^2=2 \cdot (2+\sqrt{2})\cdot(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$. You still multiply by conjugates as I did, don't you?

Comment: Yes I obtained it with conjugates. My comment is just a suggestion and surely your approach is nice and correct.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I was just wondering if maybe you found a trick I couldn't see